# Find memory held by a class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory

I am working on some Visual Programming type thing - I have a class in JavaScript like so:

```
class HoldsValues {
  queue = []
  otherStuff = {}

  getMemoryUsed(){
    // rough calculation/approximation
   return this.queue.size * 50;
  }
}
```

as the queue in the class grows, is there a way to know how much memory is being used by this class, or do I just need to do those calculations manually somehow knowing the size of the queue array etc?

Comment: There's no native way to get memory use in javascript and nodejs doesn't add such a feature to the language.

Comment: I guess just implement a method that does rough calculation